# Armature with no deformation?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I'm looking to create a simple animation.
Where sphere are moving and rotate 
[image: spherical arm]

but when I'm parenting them to the bone I get deformation on them.
I tried to weight paint in blue but same result.
I tried to use the Empty group as explain in this video. : https://youtu.be/eF4CuIX40XE

What am I doing wrong ? 
project here : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tc3AgbKAzb-9KU3-iu3UngiwGwwrC2LD

Best 
Z

---

This what I get when using "Bones" relation 
I'm totally confused about this result I don't know what to do to resolve this

[image]

Comment: maybe you've deformed your bones in Pose mode? In that case come back in Pose mode, select all and alt S?

Comment: did nothing just create bone, size it, and extrude. 
I added a link to the project !

Comment: what deformation on what bone? If you select a ball, then shift select the armature, then switch to Pose mode, then ctrl P to parent > Bone, it should work fine, no?

Comment: I'm making some test now with bone parenting, have no deformation but strange parenting ?!
I guess I need to change some parenting relation ?

Comment: If you parent With Automatic Weight, maybe some bones have influences on some ball they are not supposed to...

Comment: yes but I painted all sphere in blue and still have some deformation issue and strange vertex deformation. 
I have to test it on the full rig, pretty sure that I will have some issue too
It seems to be something easy but it's not.

Comment: When using bone relation, and try to rotate the upper armature, the bottom sphere is rotating ?
I think I missing something, but I don't know where to look at

Comment: If a mesh is influenced by several bones, it will be stretched or deform when you move one these bones. If you've parented With Automatic Weight, it's certainly what happened. For an object like a machine, robot, non-organic thing, you'd better parent to bone or parent With Empty Groups then assign the part to the group you want. Also what you could do is join all the sphere in one unique object, unless you have a particular reason not to do so.

Comment: This is a part of my scratching head since 24hrs, I will try again
Btw thank you for taking time to answer to my question.

Comment: It's easier just to parent one sphere to the other as this is a simple animation. I think bones are overused.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to set up what I think you want to set up.  (I used 2.82 Alpha, but it should work on any >=2.80).

Start with an empty scene.  Add an armature consisting of a single "Bone".  In edit mode, extrude a second "Bone.001" from the tip, and extrude a third "Bone.002" from its tip.  Switch to object mode, and add your spheres.  In wireframe, it should look like this:

[image]

Now, LMB select the bottom sphere and Shift-LMB select the armature.  Ctrl-Tab switch to Pose mode, click the bottom bone.  It should look exactly like this, with the bottom sphere as the secondary selection (dark orange) and the bottom bone in the armature selected (light blue):

[image]

Finally, Ctrl-P Set Parent to **Bone**.

To parent the second sphere, Ctrl-Tab back to object mode, LMB select the middle sphere, Shift-LMB select the armature, Ctrl-Tab switch to Pose mode, click the middle "Bone.001", and Ctrl-P Set Parent to Bone.

For the final sphere, Ctrl-Tab back to object mode, LMB select the top sphere, Shift-LMB select the armature, Ctrl-Tab switch to Pose mode, click the top "Bone.002", and Ctrl-P Set Parent to Bone.

You should now have each sphere parented to a single armature bone, using Bone Parenting.  In pose mode, each bone should control one sphere with no deformation of the other spheres.  Here's the blend file:

[image]

Comment: It seems to work perfectly now have to give a try to the full object !
Why something that look so simple is so complicated to realized ?!
Thank you